# Печатная версия сайта

Tags: javascript, html, css, media-queries

Всем привет , пришло время делать печатную версию сайта , появился вопрос.
В html коде страницы , расположены изображения которые скрыты за пределы браузера , при просмотре печатной версии страницы все изображения оказываются на печатной страницы , и занимают всю страницу , тем самым получается 8 страниц , вопрос состоит вот в чем .

Можно ли сделать как либо , может через `@media print { }` 
Либо через js , так , чтобы при открытии печатной версии страницы , некий html код с изображениями не показывался ?
Спасибо.
Вот код

```html
<div class="container">
 <div id="content-slider">
     <div id="slider">
         <div id="mask">
            <ul>
            <li id="first" class="firstanimation">
            <a href="#">
            <img src="images/img_1.jpg" alt="Cougar" width="100%" height="100%"/>
            </a>
            <div class="tooltip">
            <h1>Cougar</h1>
            </div>
            </li>

            <li id="second" class="secondanimation">
            <a href="#">
            <img src="images/img_2.jpg" alt="Lions" width="100%" height="100%"/>
            </a>
            <div class="tooltip">
            <h1>Lions</h1>
            </div>
            </li>
            
            <li id="third" class="thirdanimation">
            <a href="#">
            <img src="images/img_3.jpg" alt="Snowalker" width="100%" height="100%"/>
            </a>
            <div class="tooltip">
            <h1>Snowalker</h1>
            </div>
            </li>
                        
            <li id="fourth" class="fourthanimation">
            <a href="#">
            <img src="images/img_4.jpg" alt="Howling" width="100%" height="100%"/>
            </a>
            <div class="tooltip">
            <h1>Howling</h1>
            </div>
            </li>
                        
            <li id="fifth" class="fifthanimation">
            <a href="#">
            <img src="images/img_5.jpg" alt="Sunbathing" width="100%" height="100%"/>
            </a>
            <div class="tooltip">
            <h1>Sunbathing</h1>
            </div>
            </li>
            
            </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="progress-bar"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Тем элементам которые хочешь скрыть в `@media print { }` присвой `display:none;`

Comment: дело в том что , тот код который я скинул это css слайдер , и мне нужно чтобы , первое изображение слайдера отображалось на принтовой странице , а все остальные нет.

Comment: Ну в таком случае решение задачи схоже. Просто скрываем все остальные изображения. Тем более как я вижу из кода, каждый тег <li> имеет свой id, а значит к ним можно обращаться не задевая другие элементы.

Answer (score 0):

В версии для печати установите общие стили в `head` для `img` или какого-то выбранного вами класса с `display:none` или же установите этот стиль для каждого `img`, например: `style=display:none`

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте стили задать так: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/print.css" media="print" />`

**Пример.**

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>TITLE</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/print.css" media="print" />
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="content-slider">
        <div id="slider">
            <div id="mask">
            <ul>
            <li id="first" class="firstanimation">
            <a href="#">
            <img src="images/img_1.jpg" alt="Cougar" width="100%" height="100%"/>
            </a>
            <div class="tooltip">
            <h1>Cougar</h1>
            </div>
            </li>

            <li id="second" class="secondanimation">
            <a href="#">
            <img src="images/img_2.jpg" alt="Lions" width="100%" height="100%"/>
            </a>
            <div class="tooltip">
            <h1>Lions</h1>
            </div>
            </li>

            <li id="third" class="thirdanimation">
            <a href="#">
            <img src="images/img_3.jpg" alt="Snowalker" width="100%" height="100%"/>
            </a>
            <div class="tooltip">
            <h1>Snowalker</h1>
            </div>
            </li>

            <li id="fourth" class="fourthanimation">
            <a href="#">
            <img src="images/img_4.jpg" alt="Howling" width="100%" height="100%"/>
            </a>
            <div class="tooltip">
            <h1>Howling</h1>
            </div>
            </li>

            <li id="fifth" class="fifthanimation">
            <a href="#">
            <img src="images/img_5.jpg" alt="Sunbathing" width="100%" height="100%"/>
            </a>
            <div class="tooltip">
            <h1>Sunbathing</h1>
            </div>
            </li>

            </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="progress-bar"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**css/print.css:**

```
@media print {
  img {
    display: none !important;
  }

  li#first img {
    display: block !important;
  }
}
```

Comment: Попробовал , не работает , тестировали?

Comment: поправила ответ.

Comment: Решил проблему , спасибо сверху подсказали , присвоил нужному изображению display:block; а ненужным display:none;

Comment: а это `img {
    display: none !important;
  }

  li#first img {
    display: block !important;
  }` не так написано?

Comment: так , но зачем присваивать !important , если можно обойтись просто display:none ?)